YARP reverse proxy transform response location for redirects
I am building a reverse proxy based on .net YARP. My aim is to have multiple applications behind by path. E.g. /kibana -> will point to my internal kibana server. Same for /grafana, etc.
Started with Kibana. I am using c# only so i can dinamically add multiple kibana servers afterwards.
I have this route:
    private static IReadOnlyList<RouteConfig> GetRoutes()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new RouteConfig
        {
            RouteId = "kibanaRoute",
            ClusterId = "kibanaCluster",
            Match = new RouteMatch
            {
                Path = "/kibana/{**catch-all}" // Match all paths under /kibana
            },
        }
    };
}

private static IReadOnlyList<ClusterConfig> GetClusters()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ClusterConfig
        {
            ClusterId = "kibanaCluster",
            Destinations = new Dictionary<string, DestinationConfig>
            {
                {
                    "destination1", new DestinationConfig
                    {
                        Address = "https://mykibana.com/" // Address of the internal Kibana service
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

Before getting into external resource loading (.js, .css etc, which I'll have to do some url rewriting), i get into the first redirect problem.
Navigating to /kibana will take my request correctly to https://mykibana.com. However, kibana does a 302 to /login?next=%2Fkibana
I have added the following transform (hardcoded for my /kibana example):
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromMemory(GetRoutes(), GetClusters())
    .AddTransforms(builderContext =>
            {
                builderContext.AddPathRemovePrefix("/kibana/");  // Remove /kibana before forwarding

                builderContext.AddResponseTransform(async (transformContext) =>
                {
                    if (transformContext.ProxyResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently || transformContext.ProxyResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
                    {
                        if (transformContext?.ProxyResponse?.Headers.Location != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var originalLocation = transformContext.ProxyResponse.Headers.Location;
                                if (Uri.TryCreate($"/kibana{originalLocation}", UriKind.Relative, out var locationUri))
                                {
                                    transformContext.ProxyResponse.Headers.Location = locationUri;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                });
            });

Yet, I am still being redirected to /login?next=%2Fkibana instead of /kibana/login?next=%2Fkibana.
Does anybody have a better solution than response transforms? Or know why don't they work?

Apparently it's not the transformContext.ProxyResponse.Headers.Location i need to change. It's the transformContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers! Since i need to change the location on the response that goes to the client, not to the proxied resource!
